# how to check if a value exists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

hi I am trying to get the column name of a dataframe which contains a specific word,

eg:
i have a dataframe,

```
NA              good    employee
Not available   best    employer
not required    well    manager
not eligible    super   reportee

my_word=["well"]
```

how to check if "well" exists in a df and the column name which has "well"

thanks in Advance!

Comment: there is only one word?

Comment: no,sometimes more than one

Comment: And it should be substring?

Comment: yes, list of strings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for check all columns and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row:

```
m = df.isin(my_word).any()
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

And then get columns names by filtering:

```
cols = m.index[m].tolist()
print(cols)
[1]
```

Data:

```
print (df)
               0      1         2
0            NaN   good  employee
1  Not available   best  employer
2   not required   well   manager
3   not eligible  super  reportee
```

Detail:

```
print (df.isin(my_word))
       0      1      2
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False   True  False
3  False  False  False

print (df.isin(my_word).any())
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

EDIT After converting  get nested `list`s, so [flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) is necessary:

```
my_word=["well","manager"]

m = df.isin(my_word).any()
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool

nested = df.loc[:,m].values.tolist()
flat_list = [item for sublist in nested for item in sublist]
print (flat_list)
['good', 'employee', 'best', 'employer', 'well', 'manager', 'super', 'reportee']
```

Comment: ok,how to add those column values to my_word, do we need to append one by one or any pandas way to add

Comment: If both are lists, simply use `+` like `my_word += cols` or `my_word = my_word + cols`

Comment: no, not only column names, I want to add all the values of the datacolumns in cols

Comment: I can do using a for loop, `for item in cols:
    my_word+=df[item].values.tolist()` but it would be better if we have pandas way

Comment: Yes, I add answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: sometimes my_word contains column name itself, in that case your solution is not working, if I read that df with index false then it will work,

Comment: how to consider column names also as a column values, I mean i have to read my df file without column heading

Comment: do you think parameter header=None?

Comment: yes, when we are doing `df.isin(my_word).any()` it should consider column names also, so I want column names =1,2,3,...

Comment: no `0,1,2` but `1,2,3` ? Then use `df.columns += 1`

Comment: ya sorry it is 0,1,2,.. how to make it

Comment: So if use `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)` get it. But if there are some columns names, use `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, skiprows=1)` - it omit first header row.

Comment: I dont want to skip rows, `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)` works for me but when it is reading "NA" it reads as NaN, how to overcome

Comment: Use `keep_default_na=False`

Comment: No it is for all data in df.

Comment: Do you think this is the fastest way? `df.isin(my_word).any()`, my dataframe is huuge... Trying with `df.eq(my_word).any()`, but too slow...

Comment: @yatu - what about numpy ?

Comment: It isn't numerical unfortunately. Otherwise I'd be working with numpy

Answer (score 6):

For checking in a specific column,you can simply check as below:

```
'test' in df.cloumn.values #which returns True or False
```

For checking in complete df :

```
df.isin(["test"]).any().any() #which will return True or False
```

Comment: How would you adapt this to get the column name or index which the condition is true for?