# Python: check if value appears anywhere in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, if-statement

I have a variable `var = myString` and a list of dataframes `dfList`. Each dataframe in the list is two columns of strings `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['x','y','z'], 'col2': ['a','myString','b']})`. If `var` appears anywhere in any dataframe in the list I need to execute a series of functions. I could check by looping through each dataframe in the list, but I am hoping for a method of checking that I can easily incorporate into part of a one line elif statement.

Comment: and your Question is?

Comment: Is there a way I can check if var appears in any dataframe in the list of dataframes as part of a one line if statement?

Comment: Does the `var` always occur in `col2`?

Comment: no it could be in either column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348206/15032126), to find if a value is present in a DataFrame, we can extend it to a list of dataframes as:

```
True in [df.isin([var]).any().any() for df in dfList]
```

Which will be `True` if var is present, `False` otherwise.

It works whether var is a string or any other type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd

var = 'myString'

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['x','y','z'], 'col2': ['a','myString','b']})



mystringIN = any((df[a] == var).any() for a in df.columns)


print(mystringIN)
```

Output

```
True
```

Comment: I have a list of dataframes, not just a single one